# How to require a specific data type in a class or object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, interface, type-alias, mapped-types, conditional-types

I know there are Record or Pick, but I don't know how to use them well or I don't fully understand. Well, what I want to achieve is that in a class or object at least it has a specific data type, for example, the class or object can contain strings, Booleans, arrays, etc., but it must necessarily have at least properties or fields with a Function type.

```
interface TypeAtLeastRequired {
    [index: string]: Function;
}

class Foo implements TypeAtLeastRequired { //<-- Error: This class must have at least one function
    msg: string = 'Hello!';
}

// or something like that:

type IsRequired<C> = {
    [K in keyof C]: C[K] ThatAtLeastBe Function;
};
```

I wish the same for literal objects ({})

Is it possible to do something like that with TypeScript?

I hope you can help me understand or find a possible solution :)

Comment: `type TypeAtLeastRequired = [index: string]: Function;` doesn't work?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlpbeN) meet your needs?  If so I can write it up, if not please elaborate on failed use cases.

Comment: @jcalz ohhh, yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for. What did you do? Could you explain it in detail if you can?, please.

Comment: Sorry for my translator English hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript that corresponds exactly to the set of JavaScript objects with at least one function-valued property.

[Index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) don't work because they don't require any properties at all (the empty object `{}` is assignable to `{[k: string]: Function}`) and because they require that any property that *is* present must be of a particular type (so the object `{a: ()=>{}, b: 0}` is *not* assignable to `{[k: string]: Function}` because the `b` property is not a function).  So we should probably give up on index signatures.

Instead we could express what you're doing as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), and a fundamentally recursive constraint (sometimes known as [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)).  So instead of `TypeAtLeastRequired` being a specific type, you do something like `T extends TypeAtLeastRequired<T>`.  The first `T` represents the type you're checking, and `TypeAtLeastRequired` is a type function you apply to `T` and get something out.  If you build that type function correctly, you can make it so that `T` corresponds to an object with at least one function-valued property if and only if `T extends typeAtLeastRequired<T>`.

---

Here's one possible implementation:

```
type TypeAtLeastRequired<T> = (
  { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Function ? unknown : never }[keyof T]
) extends never ? { "please add at least one function prop": Function } : T
```

If `T` has at no function-valued properties, then the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Function ? unknown : never}[keyof T]` will have all its properties be [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Otherwise, at least one property will not be [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) and not `never`.

By [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that mapped type with `keyof T`, we get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all its properties; if none of `T`'s properties were functions, then that union will be `never` (`never` | `never` is also `never`).  If at least one property is a function, then the union will be `unknown` (`never` | `unknown` is `unknown`).

Then we use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check this new `unknown` or `never` value against `never`.  If we had no function properties, this is `never`, and so we finally get the true branch of the conditional: `{"please add...": Function}`.  If we had at least one function properties, this is `unknown`, and so we finally get the false branch of the conditional: `T`.

So in the case where `T` has no function-valued properties, `TypeAtLeastRequired<T>` will be `{"please...": Function}`, and `T extends {"please...": Function}` is not true.  But in the case where it has at least one function-valued property, `TypeAtLeastRequired<T>` will be `T`, and `T extends T` is true.

So you can see how `T extends TypeAtLeastRequired<T>` expresses the desired constraint.

---

So now, let's use it.  If you want to use it in an `implements` clause, you have to mention the implementing class name twice.  It's repetitive, but not terrible (Java does this all the time):

```
class Foo implements TypeAtLeastRequired<Foo> { // error
  msg: string = 'Hello!';
}

class Bar implements TypeAtLeastRequired<Bar> {
  msg: string = 'Hello!';
  okay() { }
}
```

If you want to do it with object literals, you will be annoyed if you have to give the type a name just to check it.  Instead you could use a generic helper function to *infer* the type:

```
const typeAtLeastRequired = <T,>(t: TypeAtLeastRequired<T>) => t;
```

And instead of writing `const v: TypeAtLeastRequired = {...}`, you write `const v = typeAtLeastRequired({...})`.  Like this:

```
const okay = typeAtLeastRequired({
  a: 0,
  b: () => 2
})

const notOkay = typeAtLeastRequired({
  a: 0, // error! 
  b: 2
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKpKBBEAZKBDAziASlARwFcBLAJygBMAeOAPhgF4YAKAbxgG0BpGEgOxgBrKGAD2AM3gBdALQB+AFzwe0mFAAeIKP0pYYAMSL8AxiBJjB8mMaH8xAd0HL+UAG5QyMAL6cR4qThpAEp1LR09GFcPL3lgGBgOACIIABtMLFgMSkoYDBAYdOwCy1gJYzMLQQgyMQgk5SNTc0sfGGU4YGATVOx9AzExPgBbNKhhnRB9BGgUdGL8YnIqagGxBg4Aek31MlqyeJhhrABzZRwyAROmGAByAAkoVNSxAEJbgG5gby6evpgAEIYLwkUbpCb8KbwRBzDJ4QikCg0IFkDaHY5nGAXK43B5PF7vL4JMRCDBgFihDg-H7dSw4GDgWZoOGLRFUG60AA0dBYIA6MOZCwRyxo9FCjAYIC+tP49JJZJujOQgpwrJF7EOGGUAAZOYcAEbKClMBgAJm+wV+dIK9hAAHlSWBFQL5qrhUiNQktTBdTBtrt9q8YAblObvJbgEA)

Comment: Thanks for detailing the explanation, I have learned a lot with this, this is very useful, for example, when you want to make objects that will only have information, for example a DTO, etc., thank you :)